# PowerShell is Buffering Python Stdout

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, stdout

I'm running the following command from within a PowerShell script. My problem is that the output from gitstats.py is buffered.  This program can take a few minutes and I don't see any of my progress messages until the end.

```
git log -m -p --word-diff --date=iso | python d:\RepoStats\gitstats.py
```

within gitstats.py I'm printing using the following syntax:

```
sys.stdout.write("hi mom")
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
```

Any way to get the stdout from python to show realtime in Powershell?

Comment: `cmd /c git .... "|" python ...`

Comment: @wOxxOm: Assuming this fixes the problem: can you explain why and how `cmd` handles buffering differently from PowerShell in this case?

Comment: Yeah, it fixes the problem. I've been thinking about implementing a PS wrapper that's why haven't yet posted an answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm - thx, this worked but I didn't notice it at first because I was running my *.ps1 file in the PowerShell ISE which still buffered things - the command line worked.  Look forward to your official answer so I can pad your stats.