# No stdout/stdin when calling python script from powershell

Tags: python, powershell, scripting, stdout, stdin

I've got a strange situation, that makes me feel I went wrong at some point.

Environment: I'm running powershell .ps1 script (tried both: powershell and ISE) on Windows 10. In this script I'm runing python (2.7.14) script.

The issue is that I cannot see any output from this python script. This troubles me, because I cannot see the password prompt (https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html used inside) and cannot enter the password.

Tried at least following script invocation methods ($python="C:\Python27_x86\python.exe"):

- `. $python ...`
- `& "$python ..."`
- `Start-Process $python ...`
- `cmd /c "$python ..."` (as suggested in [PowerShell is Buffering Python Stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464281/powershell-is-buffering-python-stdout))

Any ideas, what is the reason for such behavior and how can I pass the password to the script?

There must be a better way to do this than e.g.: [Powershell: Capture program stdout and stderr to separate variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222088/powershell-capture-program-stdout-and-stderr-to-separate-variables/24227234#24227234)